# /Warning: Undefined variable $pdo in C:\xampp\htdocs\redsocial-master\login.php on line 10

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, visual-c++

//Warning: Undefined variable $pdo in C:\xampp\htdocs\redsocial-master\login.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\redsocial-master\login.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\redsocial-master\login.php on line 10

login.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include('dbcon.php');
    extract($_POST);
    
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    try {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from members where username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
        $stmt->execute([$username, $password]);
        /* Replace  $stmt->execute([$un, $pw]); con las siguiente lineas:
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        */
        $q = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($q == 1) {
        $_SESSION['id']= $row['member_id'];
        header("location:home.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['e']="Lo siento...! Su usuario o contraseña es incorrecta.";
        header('location:../index.php');
    }
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

conexion de la base de dato

```
<?php


$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "socialdb");

if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló la conexion a la base de datos";
}

return $mysqli;


?>
```

utilize este tambein me sale error

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = $conn->query("select * from members where username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
$count = $query->rowcount();
$row = $query->fetch();
if ($count > 0){
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['member_id'];
 header('location:home.php'); 
}else{
 header('location:index.php'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola. Observa que tu conexión a la BD (la variable), se llama `$mysqli`,  cuando haces `include` o `require` debes usar los nombres de variable como están definidos en los archivos. Por otra parte, esa es una conexión a `mysqli` y en el código la usas como si fuera PDO. Además de eso, tu consulta preparada no es tal, porque pasas los datos directamente (gravísimo error) y fallará en el `execute` de lo cual es mejor alegrarse, porque ese fallo pararía cualquier inyección de código. Debes poner marcadores para que funcione y sea seguro.

Comment: Aún hay más malas prácticas en tu código. ¿Para que usas `extract()`? No deberías pasar a usar datos de `$_POST` sin asegurarte de que existen, puedes asignarlos con fusión de null por ejemplo, o usar `isset` o `empty`. No debes confiar en `rowCount()` para saber el número de filas en consultas del tipo `SELECT` el Manual lo dice con claridad meridiana.  Y no deberías mostrar mensajes internos de la conexión, para más INRI ¡PDO muestra la contraseña de conexión en los mensajes de error! si la conexión está mal configurada y algún error ocurre. Y, ¿qué hace `return $mysqli` exactamente?

Comment: Pues lo primero es que decidas si vas a usar PDO o mysqli, son dos cosas distintas, cada una con su forma y sus métodos. Y luego arregla todo lo demás que te he señalado más arriba. Te recomendaría que leas la documentación oficial de PHP. Hay muchos tutoriales infectados de malas prácticas que se reproducen ad infinitum. No sigas ciegamente tutoriales, a menos que sean de alguien con probada experiencia en la programación.

Comment: tambien utilize este codigo pero me sale eror  `<?php
include('dbcon.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
'

Comment: $query = $conn->query("select * from members where username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
$count = $query->rowcount();

Comment: $row = $query->fetch();
if ($count > 0){
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['member_id'];
 header('location:home.php'); 
}else{
 header('location:index.php'); 
}
?>`

Comment: Como ya dije, decide si vas a usar [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) o vas a usar [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php). Haz clic en alguno de los enlaces que te llevará a toda la documentación. Eso sí, requiere más lectura y menos Youtube, pero aprenderás a programar bien, y de forma actualizada. Y eso deberías hacer con cada herramienta que quieras usar. Por ejemplo, si lees lo que dice el Manual sobre [`extract()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) verás que **no es aconsejable usarlo para datos externos como `$_GET` o `$_POST`**.